# File Uploading Class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<form action=""method="post" id="save_menu">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="menu-item-pic dropzone">
            <input name="userfile" type="file">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message">
                    <span>Click or Drop<br>Images Here</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

can i use this form tag of HTML for file uplodeing insted of form_open_multipart class of php ?

Comment: you should add `enctype=multiple/form-data`in `<form>`

Comment: You can use codeigniter form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart dont for get to load the helper in the controller or autoload it first.

Comment: The question is, why you want to use something instead form_open_multipart?It is fully customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`<form action=""method="post" id="save_menu">`  to

`<form action=""method="post" id="save_menu" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

You, have to use form tag as:

```
 <form id="save_menu" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when we upload file to the server. Where, **enctype=multiple/form-data** works only with POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace `<form action=""method="post" id="save_menu">` to

`<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('controller_name/function_name') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score -1):

**use this**
In PHP use this code insted form_open_multipart class of php